# How to achieve Indeterminate state for checkbox in Xamarin form In Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to achieve CheckBox where it works for three state.
In UWP I am able to achieve with custom Renderer with "IsThreeState" and by setting IsChecked property null. but not able to achieve in android customization. please help[image]

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT thanks! but i don't want to use third party plugin. Please suggest any custom solution.

Comment: I'm afraid that it is impossible to implement it in iOS and Android .

Comment: As a workaround , you could use ImageButton and change the background image with different states.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I got some hint from Android native and achieved it in Andorid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here I am answering my own question..**

I got this hint from android native. Here we can set three type of image resources when native control clicked and can invoke Event handler for xamarin common control.

```
      bool IsChecked;
      if (Control == null)
      {
         CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(Context); //CheckBox is Android Native control
         SetNativeControl(chkBox);
      }
        
      Control.Click += Clicked;


    private void Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(IsChecked == false)
        {
            Control.SetButtonDrawable(Resource.Drawable.ic_checked);
        }
        else if(IsChecked == true)
        {
         Control.SetButtonDrawable(Resource.Drawable.ic_Inderterminate);
        }
        else if (IsChecked == null)
        {
            Control.SetButtonDrawable(Resource.Drawable.ic_unChecked);
        }
        FormCheckBox?.InvokEvent(Element, e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android and iOS you could install the plugin
**Xamarin.Forms.InputKit** from nuget .

#### Usage

```
<StackLayout >
  <input:CheckBox Text="Option 1" Type="Box" />
  <input:CheckBox Text="Hello World I'm Option 2" Type="Check"/>
  <input:CheckBox Text="Consetetur eum kasd eos dolore Option 3" Type="Cross"/>
  [![enter image description here][1]][1]<input:CheckBox Text="Sea sed justo" Type="Star"/>
</StackLayout>
```

In your case , you need to set the Type as **Box** to display the Inderminate state .

For more details about the plugin you could refer https://github.com/enisn/Xamarin.Forms.InputKit .